# mysql_stmt_execute() fails with the "Wrong sequence"

Tags: c++, mysql, c

ALL,

I'm getting the `Commands were executed in an improper order.` trying to execute following code:

```
std::wstring query6 = L"SELECT( IF( ( SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE index_name=\'abcattbl_tnam_ownr\' AND table_name=\'abcattbl\' ) > 0, \"SELECT 0\", \"CREATE INDEX abcattbl_tnam_ownr ON abcattbl(abt_tnam ASC, abt_ownr ASC)\"));";
std::wstring query7 = L"SELECT( IF( ( SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE index_name=\'abcatcol_tnam_ownr_cnam\' AND table_name=\'abcatcol\' ) > 0, \"SELECT 0\", \"CREATE INDEX abcatcol_tnam_ownr_cnam ON abcatcoll(abc_tnam ASC, abc_ownr ASC, abc_cnam ASC)\"));";
res_stmt = mysql_stmt_init( m_db );
if( !res_stmt )
{
    std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res_stmt ) );
    errorMsg.push_back( err );
}
else
{
    if( mysql_stmt_prepare( res_stmt, m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( query.c_str() ).c_str(), query.length() ) )
    {
        std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res_stmt ) );
        errorMsg.push_back( err );
    }
    else
    {
        bool index_exist = IsSystemIndexExists( res_stmt, L"abcattbl_tnam_ownr", L"abcattbl", errorMsg );
        if( !index_exist )
        {
            res = mysql_query( m_db, m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( query6.c_str() ).c_str() );
        }
    }
    bool index_exist = IsSystemIndexExists( res_stmt, L"abcatcol_tnam_ownr_cnam", L"abcatcol", errorMsg );
    if( !index_exist )
    {
        res = mysql_query( m_db, m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( query7.c_str() ).c_str() );
        if( mysql_stmt_close( res_stmt ) )
        {
            std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res_stmt ) );
            errorMsg.push_back( err );
        }
    }
}

bool MySQLDatabase::IsSystemIndexExists(MYSQL_STMT *res, const std::wstring &indexName, const std::wstring &tableName, std::vector<std::wstring> &errorMsg)
{
    bool exists = false;
    char *str_data[2] = { NULL, NULL };
    unsigned long *str_length[3];
    MYSQL_BIND values[2];
    memset( values, 0, sizeof( values ) );
    str_data[0] = new char[tableName.length() + 1];
    str_data[1] = new char[indexName.length() + 1];
    memset( str_data[0], 0, tableName.length() + 1 );
    memset( str_data[1], 0, indexName.length() + 1 );
    str_length[0] = new unsigned long;
    str_length[1] = new unsigned long;
    values[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    values[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    values[0].buffer = str_data[0];
    values[1].buffer = str_data[1];
    values[0].buffer_length = tableName.length();
    values[1].buffer_length = indexName.length();
    values[0].is_null = 0;
    values[1].is_null = 0;
    values[0].length = str_length[0];
    values[1].length = str_length[1];
    strncpy( str_data[0], m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( tableName.c_str() ).c_str(), tableName.length() );
    strncpy( str_data[1], m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( indexName.c_str() ).c_str(), indexName.length() );
    *str_length[0] = tableName.length();
    *str_length[1] = indexName.length();
    if( mysql_stmt_bind_param( res, values ) )
    {
        std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res ) );
        errorMsg.push_back( err );
    }
    else
    {
        if( mysql_stmt_execute( res ) )
        {
            std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res ) );
            errorMsg.push_back( err );
        }
        else
        {
            if( mysql_stmt_fetch( res ) != MYSQL_NO_DATA )
                exists = 1;
        }
    }
}
delete str_data[0];
str_data[0] = NULL;
delete str_data[1];
str_data[1] = NULL;
delete str_length[0];
str_length[0] = NULL;
delete str_length[1];
str_length[1] = NULL;
return exists;
}
```

The first time function is called everything is executed correctly. However the second time the call fails with the above mentioned error.

What am I missing? Is there maybe a parameters un-bind function that needs to be called?

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

TIA!

[EDIT]:

Calling `mysql_stmt_reset()/mysql_stmt_free_result()` after _fetch() doesn't change the result.

[/EDIT]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could pinpoint which line is causing the failure.  It does appear that you are potentially executing query7 immediately after query6 in certain conditions, which seems incorrect.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, it is call to mysql_stmt_execute() inside the IsSystemIndexExist() call that fails when the function is called second time.

Comment: `if( !index_exist ) { res = mysql_query ...` then you immedately try to call `IsSystemIndexExists()` a second time, but you haven't done anything with `res`... which is a result waiting to be read from `m_db`.  You can't execute the prepared statement again until you deal with that outstanding result, can you?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I added query6 and query7. As you can see those queries are CREATE INDEX. So there is nothing get from them.

Comment: I have never known such syntax to be valid MySQL. At this point, I suspect that the issue is likely to be that you are not checking for errors after running query 6, which almost certainly must be failing, so there is something that you do need to be reading from the wire.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, nope, everything is successful. Otherwise the function won't be called even the first time. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm referring to checking for an error *after* running query 6, which is immediately before the second call to the function.  You are not checking for an error after `res = mysql_query( ... query6 ...)` and may be leaving the database handle in a state where the next command will indeed be out of order.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot,, ok, now I understand, thx. I am rewriting that code to simplify queries and will take care of that one as well.